# Resetting RxJs in Angular2

Tags: javascript, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have a the following properties

```
    private messages$: BehaviorSubject<Array<MessageModel>>;
public readonly messages: Observable<Array<MessageModel>>;
```

I'm pushing new messages with `this.messages$.next(...)`, but at some point  I want to clear the pushed data. I read about the `empty()` method, but when I try to use it with `this.messages` It says that the `Observable<Array<MessageModel>>` has no such method. I try `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: There's no `empty()` method on either `Observable` nor `BehaviorSubject`.

Comment: That's strange,because I saw it here http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html

Comment: That's an operator (or more precisely a static method) that returns an Observable that doesn't emit any value and just sends the `complete` signal right away.

Comment: this.messages$.next(); ?

Comment: Thank you @JuliaPassynkova, your answer solved my problem :)
I suppose you can post it as an answer instead a comment so I can mark it as official.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear the value use

```
this.messages$.next()
```